# Flutter - Error making a HTTP post request to my server

Tags: http, dart, flutter

So I have this Future function that is meant to make a HTTP request to my server:

```
Future getReviewsComments(List reviewIDs) async {
  Map data = {
    "reviewIDs": [reviewIDs]
  };

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.encodeFull(config.domain + '/getReviewsComments'),
    body: data
  );

  if (response.statusCode != 200){
    return false;
  }
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

And the function is run in my `initState` function like:

```
  void initState(){
    List reviewIDs = ["5c4962b37d6b5f50146b8df9", "5c4966901bd9c3141c2f4700"];
    eventActions.getReviewsComments(reviewIDs).then(
      (comments){
        print( "WORKDED");
      }
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

But when I run the App, I get this error:

```
E/flutter ( 7567): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7567): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 7567): #0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:286:25)
E/flutter ( 7567): #1      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:367:8)
E/flutter ( 7567): #2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:285:13)
E/flutter ( 7567): #3      mapToQuery 
package:http/src/utils.dart:17
E/flutter ( 7567): #4      Request.bodyFields=
...
```

Please how do fix this ?

**NOTE**: `print(reviewIDs)` returns `[5c4962b37d6b5f50146b8df9, 5c4966901bd9c3141c2f4700]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dart HTTP POST with Map<String, dynamic> as body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598879/dart-http-post-with-mapstring-dynamic-as-body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` of `http.post` may only be one of the following:

1. An array of bytes as a `List<int>`
2. A string, which will be turned into an array of bytes by encoding it in UTF-8
3. A `Map<String, String>` which will be encoded into HTML form data, i.e. x-www-form-urlencoded

You are passing in a `Map<String, List<String>>`, which is none of the above. What does your server require? Perhaps a json encoded string? (If so, use `json.encode(data)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try returning response from your Future function and get the response into list.

Example:

```
Future<http.Response> getReviewsComments(List reviewIDs) async {
  Map data = {
    "reviewIDs": [reviewIDs]
  };

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.encodeFull(config.domain + '/getReviewsComments'),
    body: json.encode(data)
  );

  return response;
}
```

And then in you `initState` function extract that response from server

```
void initState(){
  List reviewIDs = ["5c4962b37d6b5f50146b8df9", "5c4966901bd9c3141c2f4700"];
  eventActions.getReviewsComments(reviewIDs).then(
    (response){
      print('Response from server is: ${response.body}');
    }
  );
  super.initState();
}
```