# Sending int and boolean at body of http post method in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi I have a http post as

```
final http.Response response = await client.post(
      'http://someurl/',
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Authorization": token
        },
        body: {
          "isItTake": false,
          "servisID": 1
        }
    );
```

But when I try this post method I get  "Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast". I can change the API to expect string but I wonder if there is a work around to send int or boolean.
Note that When I send a similar request on postman everything is fine. 
Edit: 
Postman: 
POST /someendpoint/ HTTP/1.1 
Host: somehost 
Authorization: Token sometoken 
Content-Type: application/json 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Postman-Token: 20582fd0-c980-2d0d-fb2f-3bdd87d767f5 \

{
"isItTake": false,
"servisID": 1
}

Comment: using everything is same way on postman? headers, body, etc..? If yes then it should work..  copy/paste postman curl on question just to check things if anything differs..

Comment: @jignesh I edited the question as you asked. I believe I do everything as I did in postman.

Comment: I can't see "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in postman curl.. Can you try without that on Flutter?

Comment: @jignesh I have tried it nothing changes.

Comment: hmm.. I can't see any other diff at the moment.. seems like need to try with some endpoint to mimic this behaviour.

Comment: Seems like added answer can help..

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the request body values as Strings and see if that works. I've faced this issue before with type mismatch with the request bodies of http requests and I'm not quite sure as to why it throws exceptions like that even though the documentation for the api clearly specifies the type for each value in the request body. Try this:

```
final http.Response response = await client.post(
      'http://someurl/',
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Authorization": token
        },
        body: {
          "isItTake": 'false',
          "servisID": '1'
        }
    );
```

Or in case if you have your values in some bool and int variables:

```
final http.Response response = await client.post(
      'http://someurl/',
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Authorization": token
        },
        body: {
          "isItTake": isItTake.toString(),
          "servisID": servisID.toString()
        }
    );
```

Comment: As I said in the question I can do that but is there a work around. Please read the question.

Comment: @Savrona Pardon me if I'm mistaken but, in your question you said you don't prefer changing the api to expect strings. Well, using the solution I provided, you don't have to change it. The api will still be expecting boolean and int. It's just in your request body you'll send them as Strings. Weirdly enough, this is what worked for me in a project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String encoded = json.encode(theMap);` then post `encoded`. If you need a particular character encoding (e.g. utf-8) then further encode the string using `utf8.encode(encoded)` and post the resulting byte array. (The second step should be unnecessary for utf-8 as I think that is the default.)

It's worth considering what the 3 variants do:

- `List<int>` - sends an opaque byte array
- `String` encodes the string into bytes using a character encoding - and sends the byte array
- `Map<String, String>` - encodes the string key/value pairs in
  `x-www-form-urlencoded` and sends that.

If you want to send more complex data then you need to convert it into one of the above (and the server needs to know how to decode it). That's where the `content-type` header is useful. Ultimately, the server receives a byte array and converts it back into, for example, a string, or some json, or a set of form fields, or an image. It knows how to do this based on the header and any specified encoding.

Complete Credit: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54598948/2145844)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "isItTake": 'false'