# Type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>? Tried some solutions but still Stuck

Tags: flutter, http-post, mobile-development

Here is my code:

Map<String, dynamic>? myMap = {
'conversationId': iD,
'type': 'text',
'data': _controller.text.toString(),
'msgLength':_controller.text.length,
'senderId': Provider.of(                                                 context,listen: false).id,
'createdOn': 190823,
'messageState': 'delivered',
'isDeleted': 0,
'id': 3048,
};

```
          String encoded = json.encode(myMap);

     // Make the POST request and wait for the response
     final response = await postRequest(url: conversationUrl,
                                        body: encoded,
                                        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},);
```

BUT I AM SHOWN a RED LINE UNDER encoded in the body parameter, with the error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'

I have tried ([Dart HTTP POST with Map<String, dynamic> as body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598879/dart-http-post-with-mapstring-dynamic-as-body)) changes, now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas! the answer to my problem is to use dart.io library's httpRequest method that allows custom headers in a http request !

Answer (score 1):

The body takes the map, not the encoded string. Simply use

```
body: myMap,
```

Comment: I noticed this and tried myMap too, but I got this error: "Error making POST request: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

So what I think might be happening is an issue in the way the json is being encoded, maybe

We usually do

```
body: jsonEncode(<String, String> {
        'key1':'value1', //hard coded
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': variable, //for variables given to the post function in the repository
        'boolean_key': booleanVar ? "True": "False", //for boolean variables
      }
      )
```

Also, the docs for json encode say this:

```
Shorthand for json.encode. Useful if a local variable shadows the global json constant.
Example:
const data = {'text': 'foo', 'value': 2, 'status': false, 'extra': null};
final String jsonString = jsonEncode(data);
print(jsonString); // {"text":"foo","value":2,"status":false,"extra":null}
```

Try making the String encoded of type **final**

Comment: I have also tried making encoded String final but this still gives  a RED LINE UNDER encoded in the body parameter, with the error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'  and also tried jsonEncode(<String, String> {}) way, this throws error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, String>?'